# Getting a 502 Bad Gateway when trying to run a POST request for application on Lync UCWA on VPN

Tags: html, rest, vpn, lync, ucwa

I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway when trying to run a POST request for application info on Lync UCWA ("Policy prevents request from being proxied."). When I do a request without SSL, I get a 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Is this becouse I am on VPN and not on the internal network? There are some policy on VPN or the IIS internal that denies me access?

I have not tried it internal yet. Anyone else with this experience?

Comment: You say you're posting to the application resource when you get this error, did you already manage to authenticate the user?

Comment: Yes, I get the token and I post the token to the site. Then I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give my captain obvious answer, don't know lyncs config details well I'm not really a sysadmin.

503
You've got the request or lyncs response blocked on ucwa or something else in between. There's somewhere to configure that policy it's talking about.

try fiddling with this request to get your policy list (I guess there's a shot that's blocked too) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn323680.aspx

403 is forbidden.
I don't think lync has port 80 http open by default.

Gotta drop some configuration on your tmg/isa server it looks like to open that stuff. The policies are probably in there somewhere too.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh690011(v=ocs.15).aspx that has a snippet for how to open port 80 at the end, and I'm going to take a wild guess at what your trying to do and say the first part is likely relevant too.